# Stumped! .htaccess regex RewriteRule woes

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Please forgive me if this has been explained elsewhere already. I've been Googling and trying things for the last two hours and still can't get it working. None of the examples I've found so far seem to quite fit.

This seems like it should be incredibly simple. I'm trying to rewrite the following URLs (original and target):

```
/product.cfm?item=17
/product/17
```

and

```
/parts.cfm?part=12
/speakers/12
```

...and I can't get anything to work.

I've tried things like:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^part=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/parts.cfm$ /parts/$1 [NC,R=301]
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^/parts.cfm?part=(.*)$ /parts/$1 [NC,R=301]
```

But I'm just getting a 404 page, that indicates that it's not going through. And, sadly, I don't have access to logs on this server, so I can't see what's really going.

Am I going about this all wrong? Is there some other way to handle these? It's probably just a one-character typo, isn't it?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use

```
RewriteRule ^product/(\d+)$ product.cfm?item=$1 [L]
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^speakers/(\d+)$ parts.cfm?part=$1 [L]
```

to accomplish your goals.

The first part is the incoming URL - the second part is the part that you actually want the server to use. Looks like you've got them mixed up right now.